# Simultaneous read/write operations on file from different processes: working on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, file

I'm creating a SQLite database with data from a .log file. The log file is updated by a machine each time it performs an operation. What I achieved to do in Windows is to monitor this file for changes, and as soon as it's modified - externally by the machine via serial communication, but I'm simulating this behavior by opening the file in notepad and adding new lines - to read the new line and put the data into the database.

The problem is when I try to do the same with my Linux machine, because apparently the python program sees no modifications in the file even after it's been updated and saved. Nevertheless, If I close and reopen the file within the program to re-read it, the modifications are there (but I still can't detected new modifications).

I've actually tested the same code on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running on Raspbian, and it works as expected: the modifications are *toute de suite* detected and the data is added to the database.

The .log file has the format shown below.

> ```
> 01  (PB)      008   Pa    6.01  bar         12/11/2055  07:25:17    
> 01  (PB)      008   Pa    6.01  bar         12/11/2055  07:26:39    
> 01  (PB)      009   Pa    6.00  bar         12/11/2055  07:29:45
> ```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
import re
import sqlite3
import os, time

if __name__=='__main__':
    fd = open('putty.log', 'r')

    # Ici on crée la base de données qui gardera les résultats des tests

    connection = sqlite3.connect('banc_tests.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    create_db = """
    CREATE TABLE tests (
        reference VARCHAR(15),
        num_serie VARCHAR(15),
        operation TINYINT,
        resultat CHAR(2),
        fuite SMALLINT,
        unite VARCHAR(5),
        pression FLOAT,
        pUnite VARCHAR(5),
        date DATE,
        time TIME
    );
    """

    cursor.execute(create_db)

    # Here we look for the testing bank frame's format with regular expressions
    # For now we are ignoring all information about low pressure, PE test, etc.

    while 1:
        where = fd.tell()  # Garde la position actuelle du curseur dans le fichier
        line = fd.readline() # On lit la ligne suivante
        if not line:
            time.sleep(1)
            fd.seek(where)  #Si il n'y a rien à lire on retourne à la position précédente.
        else: 
            # The ([\+\-]?\d*)\s*(\w*) segment in intended to ignore whitespaces in the faulty testing lines
            # as well as to grab the leak pressure for ordinary tests. To change it back to the original
            # version, it suffices to replace every * by a +.
            print(line)
            found = re.findall(r'^\s+(\d+)\s+\((\w+)\)\s+([\+\-]?\d*)\s*(\w*)\s+(\d+\.?\d+)\s+(\w+).*\s(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+:\d+)', line)

            # La commande findall retourne une tuple dans une liste, donc ici j'enlève la tuple et laisse
            # juste la liste avec les éléments dedans.

            if found:
                temp = list(found[0])

                insert_values = """
                    INSERT INTO tests (reference, num_serie, operation, resultat, fuite, unite, pression, pUnite, date, time)
                    VALUES ("{ref}", "{num_ser}", "{op}", "{res}", "{fuite}", "{unt}", "{pression}", "{pUnt}", "{date}", "{time}"); """

                insert_command = insert_values.format(ref='', num_ser='', op=temp[0], res=temp[1], fuite=temp[2], unt=temp[3], pression=temp[4], pUnt=temp[5], date='{}-{}-{}'.format(temp[8], temp[7], temp[6]), time=temp[9])
                cursor.execute(insert_command)

                connection.commit()
```

I thought that it was a problem of blocking behavior of the open() function, so I tried using the **os.O_NONBLOCK** flag together with **fcntl**; it didn't work, though.

Does anyone have ideas on what could be causing this different behavior between Linux (Debian 10 Bluster) and Windows? And what could I do to solve the problem of the Linux side?

Comment: What type of filesystem do you have on that Linux? Ext4?

Comment: depends on FS, NFS for example, will not update those times. Better is to poll the file and check it size and to read new content from the last position

Comment: I have an ext4 filesystem, @pako. That must be it, then. I verified on my Windows machine and it's got a NTFS filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Paul-AG. I'm going to try this way and if it works as I expect I'll post the results here as a solution.

Comment: @EmanoelCosta hmm, basic example works for me (I have ext4 also): https://pastebin.com/AbNhkSnA Does it work on your linux system?

Comment: @pako, yes, it works exactly like yours. And it reminds me, as I said in the question, that it worked on my Raspberry which runs on a ext4 filesystem as well. I'm going to try echoing into the file the text I was entering by hand.

Comment: @pako, I've tested it know and verified that doing 'echo "01 (PB)  006 Pa  6.01 bar  12/11/2055  08:48:54" >> putty.log' produces the expected behavior, while adding a line at the end of the file through a text editor (Kate, Pluma, vim, nano; I've tried everything) does not.

Comment: @EmanoelCosta: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I found the problem. This is because `inode` of a file has changed after save in editor.

You could use `vim` and set `set backupcopy=yes` to prevent this behavior (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupcopy')

To observe this behavior you could use `ls -li` which will show you the `inode` of a file.

```
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ ls -li putty.log 
10263515 -rw-r--r-- 1 pawel pawel 87 wrz  5 14:10 putty.log
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ echo 'test' >> putty.log 
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ ls -li putty.log 
10263515 -rw-r--r-- 1 pawel pawel 92 wrz  5 14:14 putty.log
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ vim putty.log 
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ ls -li putty.log 
10263513 -rw-r--r-- 1 pawel pawel 97 wrz  5 14:14 putty.log
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$
```

The first column presents `inode`. As you can see after vim editing it has changed and that's why your script can't see those changes (because editor overwrite this file).

Comment: Thank you really much, @pako! I did ":set backupcopy=yes" in Vim and the added line was shown in my program just as I expected.